# Reading a xml file in c++

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I want to read a .xml file and access its tags in c++. I used "QDomDocument":

```
QDomDocument m_doc;
QFile file_read( "test.xml" );
```

but receive this error:

> "‘QDomDocument’ was not declared in this scope"

I know that I should add a library to my source code like:

```
#include ...
```

but I don’t know which library is suitable for using "QDomDocument", can any one help me, please. I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Did you try searching `QDomDocument` in your header files?

Comment: is it the name of a header file?

Comment: No, it's the name of the class. The name will be mentioned in the header which defines the class and the header should therefore be easily found by searching the name within your headers.

Comment: `QDomDocument` appears to be part of qt. There is a man page for it: http://linux.die.net/man/3/qdomdocument . Are you using qt for anything else though? If not, there are probably better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt have well designed [docs](http://doc.qt.io/).
Almost every class in Qt have own header same as class name. just type^

```
#include <QDomDocument>
```

But there in Qt is one hideout. Qt pretty big lib and it dived into few modules. And [QDomDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html) is placed in [XML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-index.html).

And for compiling you also need add line to projectfile(typical auto genereted by qtcreator [projname].pro):

```
QT += xml
```

Answer (score 0):

`QDomDocument` is part of library [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/).  In order to use it you need to get the Qt library and set it up on your machine.  Then you need to link your project to the Qt library.